# Loop through array to check the availability of the given url's

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I have an array with some urls. i want to check if they are online. 
My idea was to iterate through the array. Or is there an better way to get the result?

Here is my code:

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var options = [{
    method: 'HEAD',
    host: 'codepen.io',
    port: 80,
    path: '/subash/pen/koCvm'
}, {
    method: 'HEAD',
    host: 'google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/'
}, {
    method: 'HEAD',
    host: 'tutsplus.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/courses/introduction-to-wordpress-plugin-development'
}];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    console.log(options[i].host);
    var req = http.request(options[i], function(r) {
        console.log('\n***************************************');
        console.log('\n', JSON.stringify(r.headers.status));
        console.log('***************************************\n');
    });
    req.end();
}
```

Something is wrong, but i cannot find the mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by something is wrong?

Comment: Just the last one is ok.

The output in the console:

***************************************

 undefined
***************************************


***************************************

 undefined
***************************************


***************************************

 "200 OK"
***************************************

Comment: Use `r.statusCode` to see the HTTP Response Code. `status` header may not be set always.

Comment: No, r.status is good. 
i mean why the first two outputs are undefined

Comment: `status` header may not be set always.